# max-height ignored in child elements on Android 4.2

Tags: android, css

On Android 4.2.2's built-in browser, I defined a `height` on an element that's greater than its `max-height`. So it uses the `max-height`, as expected.

But there's a child element with 100% `height`, and it seems to inherit its parents `height` but not the `max-height`. As a result, it spills out of the parent, when it's intended to be contained within it.

I can sort of fix this by copying the `max-height` setting to the child, but the parent's borders/padding still prevent the child from being completely contained within the parent.

Is there a good reason/fix for this? It doesn't seem to happen on other browsers, like Chrome.

[image: Example]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .a {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        max-height: 50%;
        height: 500px;
        border: 20px solid red;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .b {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 20px solid yellow;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="a">
      <div class="b">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it work with your setup to simply have the child be position:absolute;?

```
.b {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 20px solid yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```